# Crash when running a command

Tags: java, bukkit

**Code**

MainClass: http://pastebin.com/U99LAQ6z
ListenerClass: http://pastebin.com/ZF5i8mw1

**Explanation**

I was working on my plugin and I am currently working on the portion that creates Lobbies. Basically what I have it do is when the player left-clicks with the position wand they set point 1 and when they right click they set point 2. What I have is a block selector that selects the first block then it selects all the blocks on the Y and all the blocks on Z and then on X till they equal the point2. It logs each of these blocks into a HashMap so I can call the blocks later when needed. My Problem is I think I have an infinite for loop or something like that because the console gives me an error. Sometimes it also gives me a longer stacktrace and im just confused about this.

So what I am trying to do is create a simple base that I am going to use for all of my future plugins that require areas defined. What this is suppose to do is when a player runs the command positionwand it gives them a tool that lets them select points. Left Clicking selects point1 and Right Clicking selects point2. I use getPoint1 and getPoint2 to get them because i store the points within a HashMap. Once the player has selected the points they run the command /lobbycreate (lobbyname) and when they run the command it is suppose get and store all of the blocks within the given points. To do this I use a series of for loops. To start off with I have the variable blockSelector. I want blockSelector to start off from getPoint1 and go to getPoint2 selecting all of the blocks in between the 2 points. Then we go to my first for Loop which while blockSelector.getBlockX() != getPoint2X, getPoint2X being a variable I used to get the getPoint2's X coordinate. The point of this is so all this loop and all of the loops within this loop will continue until both blockSelector and getPoint2X have the same value. Within this loop I have another loop that does this same thing except for with the Z-coordinate thus it selects all of the blocks on the Z coordinate but only after it does the loop within it that selects all of the blocks on the Y-coordinate. After all that goes through I add or subtract 1 depending on what replaceVar is and repeat the cycle till all 3 coordinates of blockSelector are equal to getPoint2 thus saving all of the blocks in the process. The reason for me having all of those if statements and the replaceVar is because When selecting coordinates players can select negative and postive coordinates and the getPoint1 could be greater or less than getPoint2 so I have to add or subtract depending on the 2 values.

**Console output**

```
jobisingh issued server command: /lobbycreate gulp
[09:46:50 ERROR]: The server has stopped responding!
[09:46:50 ERROR]: Please report this to http://www.spigotmc.org/
[09:46:50 ERROR]: Be sure to include ALL relevant console errors and Minecraft crash reports
[09:46:50 ERROR]: Spigot version: git-Spigot-b2c2c63-a3cb1bc (MC: 1.8.7)
[09:46:50 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[09:46:50 ERROR]: Server thread dump (Look for plugins here before reporting to Spigot!):
[09:46:50 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[09:46:50 ERROR]: Current Thread: Server thread
[09:46:50 ERROR]:       PID: 17 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: RUNNABLE
[09:46:50 ERROR]:       Stack:
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:                   me.jobisingh.MainClass.onCommand(MainClass.java:223)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:640)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1149)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:984)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.SystemUtils.a(SystemUtils.java:19)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:714)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:                 net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:374)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:653)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:556)
[09:46:50 ERROR]:               java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[09:46:50 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[09:46:50 ERROR]: Entire Thread Dump:
[09:46:50 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[09:46:50 ERROR]: Current Thread: Chunk I/O Executor Thread-1
[09:46:50 ERROR]:       PID: 38 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: WAITING
[09:46:50 ERROR]:       Stack:
> Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure these three loops are running indefinitely:

```
for(; blockSelector.getBlockX() != getPoint2X; blockSelector.setX(replaceVarX))
{
    for(; blockSelector.getBlockZ() != getPoint2Z; blockSelector.setZ(replaceVarZ) )
    {
        for(; blockSelector.getBlockY() != getPoint2Y; blockSelector.setY(replaceVarY))
        {
            lobbies.put(blockSelector.getBlockY(), blockSelector);
        }
        lobbies.put(blockSelector.getBlockZ(), blockSelector);
    }
    lobbies.put(blockSelector.getBlockZ(), blockSelector);
}
```

I'm using `X` as example, but it is exactly the same for `Y` and `Z`.

Your loop runs as long as `replaceVarX != getPoint2X`.
However, `replaceVarX` never changes inside the loop, so there are two possibilities:

- `replaceVarX == getPoint2X`
  The loop runs once.
- `replaceVarX != getPoint2X`
  The loop runs indefinitely.

However, you make sure that the first one is never the case:

```
if(getPoint1X > 0 && getPoint2X > 0 && getPoint1X < getPoint2X)
{
    replaceVarX = blockSelector.getBlockX() + 1;
}
else if(getPoint1X > 0 && getPoint2X > 0 && getPoint1X > getPoint2X)
{
    replaceVarX = blockSelector.getBlockX() - 1;
}
else if (getPoint1X < 0 && getPoint2X < 0 && getPoint1X < getPoint2X)
{
    replaceVarX = blockSelector.getBlockX() + 1;
}
else if (getPoint1X < 0 && getPoint2X < 0 && getPoint1X > getPoint2X)
{
    replaceVarX = blockSelector.getBlockX() - 1;
}
else if (getPoint1X > 0 && getPoint2X < 0)
{
    replaceVarX = blockSelector.getBlockX() - 1;
}
else if (getPoint1X < 0 && getPoint2X > 0)
{
    replaceVarX = blockSelector.getBlockX() + 1;
}
else if (getPoint1Z < 0 && getPoint2Z < 0 && getPoint1Z < getPoint2Z)
{
    replaceVarX = blockSelector.getBlockX() + 1;
}
```

To fix this, you'd have to move all those `if / else` inside the loops, so that the variables get updated accordingly.
You'd have to split them up over the loops though, so that `replaceVarX` gets updated in the outer loop, `replaceVarZ` in the middle one, and `replaceVarY` in the inner one, otherwise you'd break the outer two loops.

A (probably more efficient) alternative would be to replace `replaceVarX` with a variable outside the loop, which defines the direction (`-1` or `+1`) for x, y and z each (I'll call them `dx`, `dy` and `dz`), and then to replace `blockSelector.setX(replaceVarX)` by `blockSelector.setX(blockSelector.getBlockX() + dx)`.
This way you could avoid **a lot** of redundant checks (and thus computation time) inside those loops.